# Buffering while pausing netStream.pause() actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, video, actionscript, flash-builder

I have a video player and I would like to implement a pause button. I want the video to pause, buffer, and then restart from the point when the user pressed pause.

I red here (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000184.html) that I just had to call netStream.pause() to pause the video and then call netStream.pause() again to resume it without flushing the buffer.

I tried that:

```
private function stopPlaying():void {
    netStream.pause();
}

<mx:Image left="10" bottom="10" id="img_Live" source="@Embed(source='Assets/live.png')" visible="false" click="stopPlaying()" buttonMode="true"/>
<mx:Image left="400" bottom="20" id="plus" source="@Embed(source='Assets/plus.png')" click="stopPlaying()" buttonMode="true"/>
```

When I click on the first button, the video pauses. But when I click on the second button, the video doesn't start again.

Any idea on how I culd accomplish that ?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I have a live recorder and a live player. One guy is recording and broadcasting for several people. I would like those people to be able to pause the stream, buffer it, so that they can pause the live stream, and resume it at the exact same time when they paused it.

So my question is how can I pause a live stream and buffer it while the stream is pausing.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to is for Actionscript 2. In Actionscript 3 the [pause()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#pause%28%29) method only pauses playback. You can call the [resume()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#resume%28%29) method to resume playback.

Alternatively, you can use the [togglePause()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#togglePause%28%29) method. The first time you call it, it will pause, and the second time it will resume.

Comment: Thank you. I should have been more precise. I have a live recorder and a live player. One guy is recording and broadcasting for several people. I would like those people to be able to pause the stream, buffer it, so that they can pause the live stream, and resume it at the exact same time when they paused it.

Comment: With a live stream on resume it will resume playback but not from the point at where they paused it -- it will just start showing whatever is live on the stream. I believe you can do what you're after, but you need to subscribe to the stream w/different settings. I've never implemented that, however, so I can't offer much help. What you're after is the [DVR functionality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS236AE81A-5319-4327-9E44-310A93CA09C6Dev.html), this might help if you're using Flash Media Server.

Comment: Ok thank you. I had the idea of using the buffer, implementing a button that could augment the buffer each time you click on it in order to delay the video (that's what I'm trying to do in reality). What do you think about this idea ? Thank you again for your help

Comment: I'm not sure. You might be able to fool the NetStream into buffering. Look at the bufferTimeMax setting of NetStream -- but again when playback is resumed, my gut feeling is that it will resume from the current live point. For live streams, the player does some buffering, but that's generally only to allow for network issues. I'd look over the docs for NetStream and your media server to see if you can configure it to do what you want.

Comment: I tried to play with the Buffer. I just had a function that triggered netStream.bufferTime = 1 and it did delay the video by 1 second. The problem is that it looks like I can play on the buffer only once. I f I have two functions, one with a +1 delay and an other with a +2 only the first function I trigger will work. But I think it's a good start !